# How to enable branching in VSS

Tags: merge, branch, visual-sourcesafe

I am running Visual Source Safe 8.0.
I am trying to create 2 branches for my project, but I find that the *branch* option is dialed in the versions menu.

Can anyone tell me how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/d3b64885-e75d-4dd7-b1c2-d3066310a177

"Here's the quickest way to branch: Versions -> Share -> check the "branch after share" box."

...

"If you click that checkbox then the item will never be shared.  The branch happens immediately."

Answer (score 0):

You need to share a file before you can branch it in SourceSafe.